# Class App\Providers\Router does not exist in BoundMethod.php

Tags: laravel, error-handling, router

I have a provlem with my laravel. i have laravel peckage on repository gitlab
i try to clone it.
i found some problem and fix it. but i can not solve this one.

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxxx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php

                        : new ReflectionFunction($callback);
    }

    /**
     * Get the dependency for the given call parameter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Container\Container  $container
     * @param  \ReflectionParameter  $parameter
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @param  array  $dependencies
     * @return mixed
     */
     protected static function addDependencyForCallParameter($container, $parameter,
                                                            array &$parameters, &$dependencies)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($parameter->name, $parameters)) {
            $dependencies[] = $parameters[$parameter->name];

            unset($parameters[$parameter->name]);
        } elseif ($parameter->getClass() && array_key_exists($parameter->getClass()->name, $parameters)) {
            $dependencies[] = $parameters[$parameter->getClass()->name];

            unset($parameters[$parameter->getClass()->name]);
        } elseif ($parameter->getClass()) {
            $dependencies[] = $container->make($parameter->getClass()->name);
        } elseif ($parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
            $dependencies[] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given string is in Class@method syntax.
```

[the error from my laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLDax.jpg)

any one can help me?

Comment: run composer install

Comment: you are not showing the relevant code, but it sounds like a namespacing issue

Comment: i found my answere. it's something wrong with my composer.json. in old composer.json is laravel/framework 5.1.*.

i try to change with laravel/framework 5.2.* and i run composer update --no-scripts. it's solved. thanks for your responce all

Answer (score 0):

i found my answere. it's something wrong with my composer.json. in old composer.json is laravel/framework 5.1.*.

i try to change with laravel/framework 5.2.* and i run composer update --no-scripts. it's solved. thanks for your responce all